# How to split CSV file into parts

Tags: c#, csv, split, memorystream

How can I split the csv files downloaded from the URL? I am trying to keep the header for the split.

Example this

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
12,11,8,7,6
23,23,34,1,0
23,23,32,1,0
```

convert to

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
12,11,8,7,6

A,B,C,D,E
23,23,34,1,0
23,23,32,1,0
```

I have this code below that retrieves the URL file:

```
MemoryStream file = GetStreamFromUrl(invoiceAPI);

private static MemoryStream GetStreamFromUrl(string url)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    using (MemoryStream streamDownload = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url)))
    {
       stream = streamDownload;
    }

    return stream;
}
```

How can I be able to split the csv file and keep the header and also the files has a dynamic length can I be able to split it in only 10 rows for example because I will be uploading it for another set. Can you please show me how and explain.

Comment: Tip; use CsvHelper on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper

Comment: Tip: do NOT attempt to  process or parse CSV files using `String.Substring`, `String.IndexOf`, or `String.Split` because CSV values can contain escaped characters like quotes and commas and CSV strings can also span multiple lines - it's always best to use a reliable and proven library with a good reputation like `CsvHelper`.

Comment: unrelated: `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();` Why create a new stream that is never used? It will be set to another one inside the using block. Which will be disposed on exiting the using block, btw. I have doubts this will work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a implementation that uses the [`CsvHelper`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) NuGet package.

First make a `Row` class to map your CSV columns:

```
public class Row { 
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
    public int E { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"A={A},B={B},C={C},D,={D},E={E}";
    }
}
```

Then you can make a method that takes in the source path of the CSV file you want to read, and output path of where the new CSV files should go. You also need to specify the number of rows you want to chunk into each file. In this case its two. The method could definitely improved and handle error checking, but it shows the general idea.

```
private static void SplitCsv(string source, string dest, int numRows)
{
    // Open CSV file for reading
    using (var fileReader = File.OpenText(source))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader))
        {
            // Collect all rows
            var rows = csv
                .GetRecords<Row>()
                .ToList();

            // Iterate rows in chunks
            for (var row = 0; row < rows.Count() / numRows; row++)
            {

                // Extract chunks using LINQ
                var fileRows = rows
                    .Skip(row * numRows)
                    .Take(numRows);

                // Create output path
                var outputPath = Path.Combine(dest, $"file{row}");

                // Write chunk to file
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath, 
                    false, 
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    using (var csvFile = new CsvWriter(writer))
                    {
                        csvFile.WriteRecords(fileRows);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following files below:

**file0.txt**

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
12,11,8,7,6
```

**file1.txt**

```
A,B,C,D,E
23,23,34,1,0
23,23,32,1,0
```

Answer (score 1):

User string.Split, take the first line as its header and split rest of the lines.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: If the CSV file contains quoted values with newlines inside, using string.Split will break the file.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two versions.

## Common part

```
var dataLinesPerFile = 2;

var contentAsLines = content.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var header = contentAsLines[0];
var dataLines = contentAsLines.Skip(1);
```

## A. Version with writing whole file at once

```
// I've used foreach so that the algorithm could be used if reading line by line rather then the whole file 
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
var fileId = 0;
foreach (var line in dataLines)
{
    lines.Add(line);
    if (lines.Count() % dataLinesPerFile == 0)
    {
        WriteChunk(fileId++, header, lines);
        lines = new List<string>(); // or lines.Clear();
    }
}
if (lines.Any()) WriteChunk(fileId++, header, lines);

(...)

private static void WriteChunk(int id, string header, IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine($"File_A{id}:");
    Console.WriteLine(header);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines)); // File.WriteAllLines
}
```

## B. Version which writes line by line

```
var fileId = 0;
var lineCount = 0;
foreach (var line in dataLines)
{
    if (lineCount % dataLinesPerFile == 0)
    {
        //Close the file, create the new file and write the header
        Console.WriteLine(""); 
        Console.WriteLine($"File_B{fileId++}");
        Console.WriteLine(header);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    lineCount++;
}
// Close the current file
```

## Test

### Input

I've added a 5th line to prove the code will not loose 'stray' lines.

```
var content = @"A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
12,11,8,7,6
23,23,34,1,0
23,23,32,1,0
5,5,5,5,5";
```

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0

File_A0:
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
12,11,8,7,6

File_A1:
A,B,C,D,E
23,23,34,1,0
23,23,32,1,0

File_A2:
A,B,C,D,E
5,5,5,5,5
------------------

File_B0
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
12,11,8,7,6

File_B1
A,B,C,D,E
23,23,34,1,0
23,23,32,1,0

File_B2
A,B,C,D,E
5,5,5,5,5
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a little edit?

```
static void SplitCsv(string source, string dest, int numRows, string currency, ref List<string> outputPaths)
    {
        // Apro il file CSV per la lettura
        using (TextReader fileReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(source))
        {
            using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(fileReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {

                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

                // Raccolgo tutte le righe
                List<Row> rows = csv.GetRecords<Row>().ToList();

                // Itero le righe in blocchi
                for (int row = 0; row < rows.Count() / numRows; row++)
                {

                    // Estraggo i blocchi usando LINQ
                    var fileRows = rows
                        .Skip(row * numRows)
                        .Take(numRows);

                    // Creo un percorso di output

                    string outputPath = Path.Combine(dest, currency + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Year + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Month + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Day + $"_CashBacks{row}.csv");

                    // Scrivo i blocchi su file
                    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {

                        using (CsvWriter csvFile = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                        {
                            csvFile.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

                            csvFile.WriteRecords(fileRows);
                        }
                    }

                    outputPaths.Add(outputPath);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```